# Highcharts - How to choose a range to display with javascript？

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I looked up Highcharts' API references and couldn't find a particular function to select a time range.

My purpose is to bind a function to an input button. When I click on it, it will choose a range.

I found that in Highstock there's a range selector with built-in buttons.

Is there any existing function to do that in Highcharts? Or how can I do it with custom javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple, like a preset range requiring no interaction from user by selecting over the graph area, you can use what is explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17722992/772020).

Improving a bit, the idea is that your button handles the values needed for the range and supply them to the function below. When it runs, the graph gets redrawn, reflecting the new range.

```
function renderGraph(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax){
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        xAxis: {

            min: xmin,
            max: xmax               
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: ymin,
            max: ymax               
        },
        chart: {
            renderTo: "graph-container",
        },
        title: { text: null },
        credits: { enabled: false}

    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I tried your solution, but seems it doesn't work. I think the new chart also need a set of data. I found another solution uses Highcharts' built-in method `setExtremes`. That one works well.

Comment: You are right. The set of data is not included in the chart options because it was presumed to be there. Anyway, good to know you have found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you're able to use the built-in range selector, try specifying the `selected` option  [(api reference)](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.selected), like this:

```
rangeSelector: {
        enabled:true, 
        buttons: [
          {type: 'week', count: 6, text: '6w'},
          {type: 'week', count: 12, text: '12w'}
        ],
        selected: 1 // uses a zero-based index
      },
```

if this doesn't suit your needs, and if you're reading the chart data from json, then you could try something like the following:

```
  $('#button_id_value').click(function() {
    buildChart(some_hardcoded_time_value_selection); // you will have to specify a value that matches your json data
  });


  function buildChart(selected_time_value){
    d3.json("/path/to/your/data.json", function(error, json_data) {
      if (error) return console.warn(error);

      chart_series = json_data.filter(function(d, i){
        return (selected_time_value == d["time_value"]);
      });

      $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {type: 'column'},
          // ... more chart options ...
          series: chart_series,
          // ... more chart options ...
      });

    });
  });
```

fyi - this last solution requires [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) and jquery.